# debug codeigniter with mac gdbp

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

having some problems getting mac gdbp setup to debug my local codeigniter stuff.

Here is some details on my setup:
- MAMP Pro 1.9.2
- php 5.3.2
- xdebug 2.10 installed and is showing in my phpinfo file beside the zend stuff.
- config for xdebug in php.ini:
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=3003

When I open MacGDBp and refresh a page running on the local server I get some variables showing up in the main window, however I can't step into the code or anything. and I have a red warninng in the bottom left corner of MacGDBp saying 'Can not open file'.

Comment: Anybody have any ideas on this?  I know it's an old question but I'm running into the same problem...debugger attaches but then just says "can not open file" and I can't step into / through any code.

Comment: Same here, having same problem, can't find any info on it.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a rather old post but I had the same problem today and wanted to post my solution in case others struggle with getting it right. What fixed it for me was removing any spaces in the path to my localhost root. There was one folder with a space in it, and as soon as I renamed it and restarted servers (MAMP) and MacGDBp, I could see the code being debugged!